# Missing 3 required positional argument with sys.argv[]

Tags: python, jenkins, arguments, sys

I have a problem with a python script I call from a Jenkins pipeline.
In the main script I have this:

```
import sys

authentication = sys.argv[1]
style = sys.argv[2]
ip = sys.argv[3]
accounting = sys.argv[4]

PrintTestCases([str(authentication), str(style), str(ip), str(accounting)])
```

The function PrintTestCases is in another file and use a match-case structure

```
def PrintTestCases(authentication, style, ip, accounting):
    match accounting:
        case "NOACC":
            match [authentication, style, ip]:
               case ['NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE']:
                    print("Test Case Number 1")
                case _:
                        print("Wrong Test Case")
        case "ACC":
              match [authentication, style, ip]:
                case ['PRIVATE', 'NONE', 'NONE']:
                    print( "Test Case Number 2")
                case _:
                        print("Wrong Test Case")
```

Then I call the main script from a Jenkins pipeline like this

```
python3 -u main NONE NONE NONE ACC
```

But I always get this error

```
PrintTestCases() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'style', 'ip', and 'accounting'
```

Based on my understanding, I am passing the argument to the function via the sys.argv
Why the function does not see the required arguments?

Comment: A blind guess of mine : you might need quotation marks, your program considers ```NONE NONE NONE ACC``` as one argument. Also, yu're passing a list as an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a *list* that contains all the arguments.
Note how these two differ.

```py
PrintTestCases([str(authentication), str(style), str(ip), str(accounting)])
```

and

```py
PrintTestCases(str(authentication), str(style), str(ip), str(accounting))
```

In the first case, you're passing a single object. Use the second.

`PrintTestCases` is expecting 4 distincts arguments, but by passing `[str(authentication), str(style), str(ip), str(accounting)]` you're actually giving this list as the `authentication` argument alone, with the others unfilled.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a list as the input, which is counted as only first input. You should instead pass them as arguments to the function. Replace the `PrintTestCases([str(authentication), str(style), str(ip), str(accounting)])` with `PrintTestCases(str(authentication), str(style), str(ip), str(accounting))` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's just because you are passing a single list to the `PrintTestCases` function. Remove the brackets and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use argparse for those args? You can define the args you need so easy and set some of them as optional if you need.

```
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("authentication", help="The authentication method")
    parser.add_argument("style", help="The style")
    parser.add_argument("ip", help="The IP address")
    parser.add_argument("accounting", help="The accounting method")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    PrintTestCases([str(args.authentication), str(args.style), str(args.ip), str(args.accounting)])
```